# R xts converts numbers to strings - why?

Tags: r, format, xts

When I convert to a xts object, R changes the values from numbers to strings, which causes problems:

```
timeseries <- xts(timeseries,as.POSIXct(timeseries$Date))
timeseries <- timeseries[endpoints(timeseries,ts_ret_freq)]
```

This is the code in question.
Why is this the case? It shouldnt be.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the output of `dput(head(timeseries))`

Answer (score 8):

Because an `xts` object is essentially a `matrix` object. Hence all the columns of the xts will always be of same datatype (class)

Comment: So it will always be that way? Or would it change, if I was to drop the date column (then all the columns would be values of the number format).

Comment: If after dropping date, all other columns are numbers, then yes, iiuc.

Comment: As @GSee suggested "Please provide the output of dput(head(timeseries))"