# quantmod periodReturn function - how to handle NA Values?

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I am using the quantmod function periodReturn, it yields the right results for the column with useable values.

This is the function: `periodReturn(timeseries, period='weekly', type='log')`

This is the input:

```
                    dax_data.csv nikkei_data.csv spx_data.csv
1990-01-04 01:00:00           NA           38713           NA
1990-01-05 01:00:00           NA           38275           NA
1990-01-08 01:00:00           NA           38295           NA
1990-01-09 01:00:00           NA           37951           NA
1990-01-10 01:00:00           NA           37697           NA
1990-01-11 01:00:00           NA           38170           NA
```

This is the output:

```
                    weekly.returns
1999-11-26 01:00:00             NA
1999-12-03 01:00:00    0.026679863
1999-12-10 01:00:00   -0.003482017
1999-12-17 01:00:00    0.041124348
1999-12-22 01:00:00    0.021583488
1999-12-30 01:00:00    0.069259912
```

I want to use all three columns (ldo).

How do I tell periodReturn to just NA all the rows without data and start as soon as one exists?

Here is the `dput` of the data to make this reproducible:

```
dput(head(timeseries)) 
structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 38713, 38275, 38295, 37951, 
37697, 38170, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(6L, 3L), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tzone = "", class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), index = structure(c(631411200, 631497600, 631756800, 
631843200, 631929600, 632016000), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("dax_data.csv", "nikkei_data.csv", 
"spx_data.csv")))
```

Comment: You may want to use `PerformanceAnalytics` library.

Comment: please provide the output of `dput(head(timeseries))` as I [requested yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15635590/r-xts-converts-numbers-to-strings-why#comment22185688_15635590)

Comment: dput(head(timeseries))
structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 38713, 38275, 38295, 37951, 
37697, 38170, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tzone = "", class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), index = structure(c(631411200, 631497600, 631756800, 
631843200, 631929600, 632016000), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), .Dim = c(6L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("dax_data.csv", 
"nikkei_data.csv", "spx_data.csv")))

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `timeseries` as an argument use

```
   timeseries[apply(!is.na(timeseries), 1, all), ]
```

Comment: This surpresses all the error messages, but I only got one column as the output. I want all columns to be put out.

Comment: All the NAs are deleted now, but I dont want them to be deleted, I just want them to be omitted when calculating the returns.

Answer (score 0):

`periodReturn` does not work for multi-column timeseries data. Hence, we have to apply it to all columns and combine the output

```
weekly_return = do.call(merge.xts,lapply(colnames(timeseries),function(x){ 
z = periodReturn(timeseries[,x],period = "weekly",type="log");
colnames(z) = x;
return(z) 
} ))
```